# Element with auto width does not expand

Tags: css, html, css-float, nav

I couldn't find a solution for this problem (the few things I found somehow not helped at all). Probably I missed something out.

The problem is simple: the nav element does not expand to its childs with, **it breaks in two lines**. It has no fixed width and I search a solution to keep it that way.

Here is one fiddle with one suggested solution. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NsXyp/)
Here is another with another advice.[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/NsXyp/2/)

The html:

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-collapse">  
<a href="">Home</a>
<a href="">About</a>
<a href="">Something</a>
<a href="">Someone</a>
</div>
```

I search after a solution, that keeps auto width, and the nav keeps floating. I tried the same solutions with list elements, but it doesnt work either way.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: It works if you put fixed padding and margin values

Comment: Thats also a solution, but it works also if I put fixed width on the element. Is there any way to keep percentage padding and margin?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the container has no width, so there's no point of reference for these percentages (1% 2% of ?). I'm afraid it's not possible what you're asking unless you define a width on `.nav-collapse`

Comment: I see now. One of them must be fixed. I was just trying to reduce media queries, but its no other way. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Post this as an answer that I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: That's not really an answer

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly then I believe that this does:

If you set nav with a width of 100%, does this not solve your problem?

Comment: That was an experiment if its possible to not set any width of any element. Since thats not possible with CSS because of what One Trick Pony said in the comments above (if the padding/margin is in percents it can not relates to the parent div with no fix width), the only real solution is Javascript to calculate a fix width when the document loads, so the nav is flexible, but it still has a width to relate. Either way, the best solution is to fix padding/margin.

Comment: Your solution works also, but then I must set absolute position to the floating elements other side (branding,short login etc.), and that makes another trouble width fixed things. So I was just curious this can be hacked in fluid layouts. Thanks anyway!